# Postgres Restore taking ages (days)

Tags: postgresql, azure

I've been working on a backup / restore for a Postgres server for quite a while now. It's an Azure Windows Virtual Machine (Windows server 2012).

The database isn't that big (near 5Gb), but the restore takes (literally) days. I've tried (several) times with different settings to restore the database, but all of the times it took days to "finish" (it didn't finish - I killed the process because I didn't see anything happening, that's why I'm running the job verbose this time).

I've now been running the job (verbose one) for 5 days straight and still it isn't finished. It's inserting rows (or at least displaying the rows), but it's still running.

Currently I'm using this command:

```
pg_restore -Fc -v --jobs=2 --host=localhost [filename]
```

Jobs is set at 2 because it's a dual core server. Like I said: different settings still very very slow.
What is wrong - should I be "tuning" the database before the restore or what?

This is a test-server setup. When we're doing with the test the current data need to be restored (again) to the new production server: we can't afford to wait days on end before the production environment comes online.

It's not pushing errors into the logs or something - it just keeps running and running and running...

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Incredibly slow disk storage? Weird. What do you see in `pg_stat_activity`? What's the server load and disk activity like?

Comment: CPU is throttling between 71 and 100% in use.
Disk is peaking every now and then to 100%, but normally around 15%
RAM is steadily 78% in use

Comment: Check disk flush rate (fsyncs) too if you can. Or iops, as distinct from disk bandwidth. The periodic peaks suggest checkpoint activity. Have you looked at the PostgreSQL log file? It might be telling you your checkpoint segments aren't sufficient, etc.

Comment: the logs are completely empty - every midnight newly created but no contents.