# Postgresql "pg_restore.exe" taking over a day to complete

Tags: postgresql, windows-server

I'm on a Windows Server 2016 machine.  I have run pg_dump.exe on a 3gb postgres 9.4 database using the -Fc format.

When I run pg_restore to a local database (9.6):

`pg_restore.exe -O -x -C -v -f c:/myfilename`

The command runs for over 24 hours.  (Still running)

Similar to this issue: [Postgres Restore taking ages (days)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28044262/postgres-restore-taking-ages-days/48466452#48466452)

I am using the verbose cli option, which looks to be spitting out a lot of JSON.  I'm assuming that's getting inserted into tables.  The task manager has the CPU at 0%, using .06MB of memory.  Looks like I should add more jobs next time, but this still seems pretty ridiculous.

I prefer using a linux machine, but this is what the client provided.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the process consuming CPU time? Might be a lock.

Comment: any logs printed? 
Maybe memory is being over-used and there is lots of switching hence the slow execution.

Comment: How do I view the logs in the UI version?

Comment: My apologies, just edited the post.  I am on a windows server 2016 machine.  I have postgres 9.6 installed on that machine.  I also have a pg_dump file locally that I ran against a 9.4 postgres db

Comment: `pg_restore.exe -O -x -C -v` is missing the filename...

Comment: I can assure you I added the file name when I ran the command.

Answer (score 0):

```
pg_restore.exe -d {db_name} -O -x c:/myfilename
```

Did the trick.

I got rid of the `-C` and manually created the database prior to running the command.  I also realized that connection options should come before other options:

```
pg_restore [connection-option...] [option...] [filename]
```

see postgres documentation for more.